# OrientDB: Is there a way to query metadata about all indexes via the API?

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB's console.sh has an INDEXES command, which gives a list of all existing indexes, like so:

```
+----+-------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+
|#   |NAME               |TYPE             |RECORDS|CLASS       |COLLATE|FIELDS           |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+
|0   |dictionary         |DICTIONARY       |0      |            |default|                 |
|1   |OFunction.name     |UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX|11     |OFunction   |default|name(STRING)     |
|2   |ORole.name         |UNIQUE           |3      |ORole       |ci     |name(STRING)     |
|3   |OUser.name         |UNIQUE           |1      |OUser       |ci     |name(STRING)     |
|4   |UserRole.Desc      |UNIQUE           |3      |UserRole    |default|Desc(STRING)     |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+
|    |TOTAL              |                 |18     |            |       |                 |
+----+-------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------+
```

Is there a way to get this information via the API (or a SQL query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted OrientDB directly, and @lvca told me about the "metadata:indexmanager" class that contains the index information I was looking for:

```
select expand(indexes) from metadata:indexmanager
```

Here's an up to date link to the documentation:

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL.html#query-the-available-indexes

Answer (score 0):

With this query you can get all metadata:

```
SELECT expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am aware of that query, but it doesn't appear to return information about indexes (unless I'm missing it).